# How can you weight date freshness in a mysql search?

Tags: mysql, search, date

I have a fairly standard search query to find related content. Among other things, it assigns scores based on relatedness of article titles and content as well as categories etc. All pretty standard stuff. I would also like to add a weighted "freshness" based on the published date of the article.

**How can I reduce the published "datetime" of the article to a score that can be compared as part of the overall score.** NOTE: the score needs to be on the order of MATCH () AGAINST etc.

Existing score select:

```
SELECT *, 
MATCH (content) AGAINST ( 'some keywords from content') ) *1 + 
(MATCH ( title ) AGAINST ( 'some kewords from title ') ) * 1.5 + 
COUNT( matching_terms ) *3, 1 ) / 5.5 
AS score
FROM ....`
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following function scales a date difference down to a given range of expected values ranging from .5 to a maximum of about 3 over a 3 year period. It can then be given a negative weight to prefer freshness.

```
SELECT *, (LN(LN(-1/(datediff(published_time, now())+1)) + 1)
```

The score over the course of three years.

[image: Wolfram alpha]

The score over one month

[image: The score over one month]

The two LN() functions are to ensure there is a ceiling in the range of 5-6 to keep it much smaller than a typical match score. It also weights it such that articles newer than 2 weeks are heavily preferred. A single LN() has a range of about .5 - 9 with the first 30 days heavily preferred.

Comment: In Theory, yes but instead of now() you would use "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" and DATEDIFF() would need to be replaced with a postgres version: http://www.sqlines.com/postgresql/how-to/datediff

Answer (score 1):

Subtract from now to get 'age' and convert to a number, e.g.

```
select 1/((now()+0 - published_date_field) as number) * your_weighting_factor;
```

Comment: The number returned is way too large to scale well.

Comment: I changed the formula with 1/

Answer (score 0):

Apply another calculation on the score, such as :-

```
 select
 (... ) + (datediff(published_time, now())  <-- diff in days
 as score
```

The above example will always push down older stories as the datediff
will always return zero or negative value.